# Accidentally replaced /usr/bin/ld with other binary file, installing through binutils just reverts back to what I replaced it with

Tags: filesystem, g++, ld

I accidentally replaced /usr/bin/ld with the lua executable. So when I run ld, it triggers the lua interpreter. When I sudo remove ld and reinstall through:

`$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils`

It reinstall ld but when I run `$ ./ld` it's still lua, oddly..

New to linux and trying to familiarize myself with the operating system and where all the library files are.

Comment: `./ld` refers to a file called `ld` in the current directory (`pwd`). Is `pwd` actually `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Yes, sorry i `cd` to `/usr/bin` and ran `sudo rm ./ld` then ran `ls | grep ld` to confirm it was gone. Reinstalled it from binutils confirmed it was there and ran ` ./ld`  since I was already in that directory. @steeldriver

Comment: When I ran it, it triggered the lua interpreter again